# Create zsh autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have a directory with projects and I create a function to cd to this directory.

```
projects_folder="/opt/work/projects/"
function pr () {
  cd $projects_folder
  if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
    cd $1
  fi
}
```

I want to create zsh autocompletion for this function

```
compdef '_path_files -W /opt/work/projects -/ && return 0 || return 1' pr
```

Also I create custom complete function

```
_pr(){
  local -a list
  for dir in $(ls $projects_folder); do
    inside_dir=$projects_folder$dir
    if [ -d $inside_dir ]; then
        list=( $list $dir )
        for d in $(ls $inside_dir); do
            double_dir=$inside_dir/$d
            if [ -d $double_dir ]; then
                list=( $list $dir/$d )
            fi
        done
    fi
  done
  compadd -a $list
}
compdef _pr pr
```

But both of these variants don`t work. Can somebody explain me that is wrong? My [.zshrc here](https://github.com/Crandel/home/blob/master/.zshrc)

**UPD:**
Solution is delete `antigen apply` from .zshrc, regarding this [issue](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/89)

Comment: Can see anything wrong with your first solution. The ` && return 0 || return 1` bit is totally superfluous. If this doesn't work for you, what is it doing?

Comment: I found solution. It was `antigen apply` in .zshrc. There are an [issue](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/89) in antigen repo